# Problems with Lazy Load and Mix It Up plugins

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, mixitup

I have a problem with my lazy-load target positioning.
Everytime I filter my list (which uses Mix It Up plugin), my images won't load on scrolldown, 'cause LazyLoad is targeting its old positioning.

How can I force Lazyload to properly target my images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old jquery lazyload isn't really made for dynamic webpages. In general the plugin only checks for user scroll. Additionally it has some flaws with runtime performance and managing memory.

I created a lazyloader, which is truly different from all other lazyloader: It uses a) highly efficient code and b) detects any visibility changes to current and future DOM elements automatically.

Here is a simple demo with mixitup:
http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/wByKeL

Everything you need to do is to add the [lazySizes script](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) and write the following markup:

```
<img data-src="img.jpg" class="lazyload" />
```

Comment: Brilliant lib to use. Will be using this on alot of projects from now on.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use the callback features of MixItUp. Here is the MixItUp documentation, https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#group-callbacks. I used onMixEnd to call my lazy loading functionality. This should ensure that all the images are in the correct place before the lazy load functionality takes over.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').mixItUp({       
        callbacks: {
            onMixEnd: function () {
                $("img.lazy").lazyload();       
            }
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that every time a sort/filter function is invoked a new lazyload instance with strong reference to those elements is created, with time and/or in case of a lot of items, the application/page will get slower and slower and consumes more and more memory.

Comment: That is a good point alexander. I think I am going to have to play around with your lazyload application tonight. Looks pretty cool from what I saw so far. Thanks!